# Perforce : Revert files without losing its modification

Tags: perforce, p4api.net

To let you understand my problem, i must give some brief explanation about the way my client application works.

First, we create workspaces with `allwrite` set, this is because our programming language (PowerBuilder) does not writes directly to txt files, it writes to 'pbl' files, which are binary.

However we dont version pbl files and to be able to version each object inside a pbl we need to run some `cmd`command, which will output the classes within the pbl file to text files (one file per class), these text files is what Perforce must version.

The problem now is that the pbls are being listed as modified files (in fact they are), but we dont want them to be marked as modified.
I could put them in a ignore file, but there are some Pbls in the repository which must be synced.

I know i could specify in the ignore file to ignore Pbls except the Pbls which are in the repository, but then these specific pbls would keep showing up as modified files when i run a `reconcile`..

What i want is to have the PBL file exactly the way it was before running the `reconcile`, unopened by perforce but modified.

Its would be ok, if i could revert them without undoing its modifications...

Or if i could run a `reconcile`for all the files, except the pbls.

Does anyone knows a way to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can revert files without refreshing their content from the repository by running 'revert -k': http://perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_revert.html

Comment: Swear i had read about `p4 revert` in the docs.. for some reason haven't seen this flag! Thank you! :)